# Table paging in asp.net html table

Tags: c#, jquery, html, mysql, asp.net

Hi guys is there a way where I can have a paging in my table?

My table is coded like this in html.

```
<table width="100%"  id="tbl_Delivered">
<tr>
    <td width="30%">
    </td>
    <td width="45%" class="GRIDVIEW_TITLE">
            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="DELIVERED"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
</tr>
    <tr >
        <td width="30%">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td width="45%">
            <div id="Delivered" runat="server">

            </div>
        </td>
        <td width="45%">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then I have a stored procedure that will place another series of td's in

```
<div id="Delivered" runat="server">

                </div>
```

Part of my stored procedure is this

```
 DECLARE @DELIVERED VARCHAR(MAX)
        SELECT @DELIVERED = ''
        SELECT ALL 
        @DELIVERED =   @DELIVERED + '<TR class="GRIDVIEW_DETAILS">' +
                                        '<TD WIDTH ="100" ALIGN="LEFT"><A HREF="/D2MS/wTransmittalSearch.aspx?ref='+RefNumber+'">'+RefNumber+'</A></TD>' +
                                        '<TD WIDTH ="100" ALIGN="LEFT">' +  airwaybillno  + '</TD>' +
                                        '<TD WIDTH ="250" ALIGN="LEFT">' +  RTRIM(UPPER(deliverto))  + '</TD>' +        
                                    '</TR>' 
        FROM #temp_delivered
        --ORDER BY deliverdate DESC
        SET @DELIVERED = 
        '<TABLE WIDTH="100%">' +
        '<TR  class="GRIDVIEW" ><TD >REFERENCE #</TD><TD>AIRWAYBILL #</TD><TD ALIGN="LEFT">DELIVER TO</TD></TR>' +
        + @DELIVERED + 
        '</TABLE>'

    select @DELIVERED AS HTML from #temp_delivered
```

Then I have a c# code to append my html code from stored procedure to the webpage

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            dsView = dm.ViewDelivered(Session["Username"].ToString());
            //gridsummary.DataSource = dsView.Tables[0];
            //gridsummary.DataBind();

            #region old
            string sDelivered = string.Empty;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = dsView.Tables[0];
            List<string> slistPostal = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                if (dr[0].ToString() == "DELIVERED")
                {
                    sDelivered = dr["HTML"].ToString();
                    Delivered.InnerHtml = sDelivered;
                }

            }
            #endregion

        }
    }
```

I am loading many data so I want to have a paging in my table, is there any way to do that? Thanks in advance.

For Tomer Klein this is the error

[image]

Comment: in your Html Wrap Your Table with jQuery DataTable,
this should do the trick.
http://www.datatables.net/

Comment: @TomerKlein It returns an exception in the javasript

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: there is no "<thead>" and "<tbody"> in your table

Comment: @TomerKlein I've already added that, still the error occurs.